# a good word in english, for human studies that are discussed in religion

Tags: single-word-requests

in religion, when we talk about human, we're talking about a being which has different faculties, and has soul, and is everlasting. we're not simply talking about social aspects of human or how they behave toward one another.

so the term need to cover these areas as well. like where have we come from, what are we doing here, where are we going, and what difference we have from animals, what are our different faculties (sense, imagination, wisdom, ... our never satisfying thirst for perfection ...) . you know, like how human is talked in philosophy.

anthropology might work, but is there a better word for it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a type of *metaphysics* or *ontology*, but I don't know what word would be specific to humans.  Ontology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology

Comment: How about Human Science: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_science?

Comment: The word is ***theology***. The way you've set it up, you are talking about a religious interpretation/understanding/investigation of humanness or humanity. Such a study is *theology* or a part of *theology*, nothing more. It is certainly not *human science* or *anthropology* (or any other science).

Comment: theology: Theology is the critical study of the nature of the divine. It is taught as an academic discipline, typically in universities, seminaries and schools of divinity.[1]. don't think theology is the word for it. since we're talking about human, and it's relation to the big picture.

Comment: This is a site aimed at linguists. Please use accepted punctuation.

Comment: And how about an example sentence? In struggling to figure out what you're actually needing a single word for

Comment: the usage of that word in a sentence would be something like this: "the most important knowledge we can acquire, is * (the word I'm looking for) . without it, advancement in other fields of knowledge is like putting the cart before the horse."

Comment: Maybe the word is "spirituality."

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with those who have said the word you are seeking is ***theology*** - "a religious interpretation of humanity" as @Drew has pointed out.

***Anthropology*** is the study of humans in society.

Another word, which sounds as if it might be what you want, but which is actually an antonym is ***humanism***, defined by Wikipedia as:

***Humanism is a philosophical and ethical stance that emphasizes the value and agency of human beings, individually and collectively, and affirms their ability to improve their lives through the use of reason and ingenuity as opposed to submitting blindly to tradition and authority or sinking into cruelty and brutality.***

Comment: thanks. but according to this definition, the word ***humanism*** simply refers to the worldly lives of humans, and how they can improve it by using reason.